# Port forwarding from public ip to local ip in other way

Tags: sockets, networking, server, tcp, router

So... if i want my tcp server can be connected by other network(not just local network), i will need to setup port forwarding in my router setting page. But it's so annoying so i'm wondering is there other way to port forwarding from public IP to my local IP address.. maybe with code?

Comment: https://github.com/anderspitman/awesome-tunneling

Comment: If the router has uPNP enabled, you can setup port forwarding programmably directly from your server code.